# Java string concatenation to integer arithmetic

Tags: java, string, time

I'm currently doing any exercise from thinking in java where you find out the number of seconds since midnight.

When printing it with a string in front the calculation of the number seconds, it seems to be using the string for further calculations. Both results no matter how I order it give me different wrong result, where as if I remove the "Seconds since midnight: " string it gives me the correct result. I've parenthesized to make sure it's following PEMDAS, but I dont understand how that string is making things change

```
    String hour, minute, second;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String theTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime()).toString();

    hour = theTime.substring(0,2);
    minute = theTime.substring(3,5);
    second = theTime.substring(6,8);
    int intHour = Integer.parseInt(hour);
    int intMinute = Integer.parseInt(minute);
    int intSecond = Integer.parseInt(second);

    System.out.println("Seconds since midnight: " + (intHour * 3600) + (intMinute * 60) + intSecond);
    System.out.println("Seconds since midnight: " + intSecond + (intMinute*60) + (intHour*3600));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parenthesis around your calculations, the order of operations goes from left to right.

This will first concatenate the string with the integer instead of calculating the correct value.

```
System.out.println("Seconds since midnight: " + (intSecond + (intMinute*60) + (intHour*3600)));
```

Here's a simplified example:

```
int value1 = 5, value2 = 10;

System.out.println("result " + value1 + value2); 
System.out.println("result " + (value1 + value2));
```

Output

> result 510
>   result 15

A small breakdown to what exactly happens.

Situation 1: `"result " + value1 + value2`

- String is concatenated with an integer => Result is a string
- Resulted string is concatenated with the other integer

Situation 2: `"result " + (value1 + value2)`

- String is concatenated with HOOOOOOLD IT RIGHT THERE! A parenthesis has been detected.
- Parenthesis are executed => Result is an integer
- Continue by concatenating the string and the resulted integer.

This sample might be insightful as well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(valString() + (val1() + val2()));
}

static int val1() {
    System.out.println("val 1");
    return 5;
}

static int val2() {
    System.out.println("val 2");
    return 10;
}

static String valString() {
    System.out.println("val string");
    return "result ";
}
```

Output:

> val string
>   val 1
>   val 2
>   result 15

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is this:

```
  int secondsSinceMidnight = intSecond + (intMinute*60) + (intHour*3600);
  System.out.println("Seconds since midnight: " + secondsSinceMidnight);
```

The problem with your implementation is that does not compute the whole secondsSinceMidnight value, rather it concatenates each integer to the string.